# how to improve kmp algorithm to find overlap result

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int *get_next(char *arr){
        int *next = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * strlen(arr));
        next[0] = -1;
        int i = 0;
        int j = -1;
        while( arr[i] != '\0' ){
                if( arr[i] == arr[j] || j == -1) {
                        i++;
                        j++;
                        next[i] = j;
                }else{
                        j = next[j];
                }
        }
        return next;
}
void kmp(char *arr, char *pat){
//      printf("in %s find %s ", arr, pat);
        int *next = get_next(arr);
        int i = 0;
        int j = -1;
        while( *(arr + i) != '\0'){
                if( j == -1 || arr[i] == pat[j] ){
                        j++;
                        i++;
                }else{
                        j = next[j];
                }

                if( j == strlen( pat )){
                        printf("at %d\n", i - j);

                }
        }
}
void main( void ){
        char test[] = "aabaaba";
        kmp(test, "aba");
}
```

I compile this and run it, it was ok, but if i change test with "aababa"

I just get one answer 1;But the answer is we can find aba at position 1 and 3

### This error occur when two result has overlap

anyone has a good idea to improve this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

```
void kmp(char *arr, char *pat){
    int found = 0, len1, len2, i = 0;
    char *temp = NULL;

    len1 = strlen(pat);
    len2 = strlen(arr);

    temp = calloc(len1 + 1, 1);
    if(temp == NULL){printf("Error in calloc \n"); exit(1);}

    for(i = 0; i < len2 - len1 + 1; i++){
        memmove(temp, &arr[i], len1);
        if( !strcmp(temp, pat) ){
            found = 1;
            printf("at position %d ", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(temp);

    if(!found){printf("No match! \n");}

    return;
}
```

valter

Comment: This will not work if there are 2 or more letters in overlap. Try with "aabaabaa" for array and "aabaa" for pattern. You should reset `i` to the next position after a pattern is found. Something like `i = i - len + 2`